# Can you simplify this term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$X=\frac{\frac{c}{r^2}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T+1}}}{\frac{c}{r}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^T}-1}$$

Comment: @EricS. Yes all are scalars and  you may assume $r>0$.

Comment: If you rewrite both enumerator and denominator into a single fraction, i.e. of the form $X=\frac{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}{\frac{\gamma}{\delta}}$, you can rewrite that into $X=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{\delta}{\gamma}$ and a lot of terms will drop

Comment: @EricS. It would be very nice if you could do that... ; )

Comment: Just be patient.  Take lots of paper and multiply top and bottom by common terms.  first by $(1+r)^T$.  That will cause $\frac {1-c}{(1+4)^{T+1}}$ to reduce to $\frac{1-c}{1+r}$.  Then by r.  Eventually the whole thing should become manageable.  Takes patience though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\frac{c}{r^2}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T+1}}}{\frac{c}{r}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^T}-1}=
\frac{r^2}{r^2}\frac{\frac{c}{r^2}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T+1}}}{\frac{c}{r}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^T}-1}=
\frac{{c}+r^2\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T+1}}}{r{c}+r^2\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^T}-r^2}=\\
\frac{(1+r)^{T+1}}{(1+r)^{T+1}}\frac{{c}+r^2\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T+1}}}{r{c}+r^2\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^T}-r^2}=
\frac{{c}(1+r)^{T+1}+r^2({1-c})}{r{c}(1+r)^{T+1}+r^2({1-c}){(1+r)}-r^2(1+r)^{T+1}}=
\frac{{c}(1+r)^{T+1}+r^2({1-c})}{r\left({c}-r\right)(1+r)^{T+1}+r^2({1-c}){(1+r)}}=
\frac{{c}(1+r)^{T+1}+r^2({1-c})}{\left(({c}-r)(1+r)^{T}+r({1-c})\right){(1+r)r}}
$$
$$%=\frac{c-r^2 (c-1) (r+1)^{-T-1}}{r(c -r)-r^2(c-1)  (r+1)^{-T}}$$

would this help?

Comment: Thank you. Can you please also show the steps how to get there?

Answer (score 3):

$X=\frac{\frac{c}{r^2}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T+1}}}{\frac{c}{r}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T}}-1}$
$====================$
$X=\frac{\frac{c}{r^2}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T+1}}}{\frac{c-r}{r}+\frac{1-c}{(1+r)^{T}}}$
$====================$
$X=\frac{\frac{c(1+r)^{T+1}+(1-c)r^2}{r^2(1+r)^{T+1}}}{\frac{(c-r)(1+r)^{T}+(1-c)r}{r(1+r)^{T}}}$
$====================$
$X=\frac{\frac{c(1+r)^{T+1}+(1-c)r^2}{r(1+r)}}{\frac{(c-r)(1+r)^{T}+(1-c)r}1}$
$====================$
$X=\frac{(c(1+r)^{T+1}+(1-c)r^2)1}{r(1+r)((c-r)(1+r)^{T}+(1-c)r)}$
$====================$
$X=\frac{c(1+r)^{T+1}+(1-c)r^2}{r(1+r)((c-r)(1+r)^{T}+(1-c)r)}$